# clean a badly-encoded text in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have some texts in a Pandas dataframe (in a specific column called `text`)

here an abstract (converted to list):

```
['    baby k jax  io ieri sera stavo fuori come arisa stavo piã¹ storta della torre di pisa lui che strusciava ha detto no striscia la visa che quando cala il basso baby senti che ti arriva  tengo duro  no pilota non câx80x99ã¨ musica solo slogan pussy power  super lova dio perdonami  vulva loca  no  non disturbarmi mentre sto guardando swaggando  please vuole toccare i tasti come alicia keys  mi piace quando fai certe cose certe cose quando fai certe cose mi piace quando piace quando fai certe cose certe cose quando fai certe cose mi piace quando piace quando fai  ero con le bambole coi bomber guardavano le bambole coi bomber qualcuno ha detto andale andale si sono accese fiaccole le trombe sempre in giro come gran turi lenti scure quando fatturi non fare la dura che non duri punta su di me che vado all in  in discoteca bevo fino a diventare analfabeta chi vuoi diventare alfa o beta a giudicare al tuo like zeta zeta zeta vai bello come un tale vous brucio ste barbie faccio un barbecue mi piace il tuo grande cervello sai cosa ã¨ meglio fare scopa col settebello  certe cose certe cose quando fai certe cose mi piace quando piace quando fai certe cose certe cose quando fai certe cose mi piace quando piace quando fai certe cose certe cose quando fai certe cose mi piace quando piace quando fai certe cose certe cose quando fai certe cose mi piace quando piace quando fai  cosa c ã¨ sotto il tuo gucci tarocco mi piaci quasi troppo mi piaci quando fai   guardo e non tocco manca poco che sbrocco al tuo amico a scrocco mi piaci quando fai    mi piaci quando fai cose che le altre non fanno ãx88 lunedã¬ sera e brindi come a capodanno bevi cento shot ma reggi bene lâx80x99alcol ãx88 martedã¬ in palestra fai squat con il tacco loro slacciano bottoni se fa caldo quando lo fai tu invece suda qualcun altro arrostiscono se al cinema câx80x99ã¨ una scena di sesso tu invece dici che puoi fare meglio loro a casa con il tipo con la tuta con le felpe fanno foto con roba aderente per i like loro hanno una visa che usano raramente tu hai il reggiseno solo che non usi mai loro seguono la moda tu la fai loro miu miu jimmy choo tu minigonna e nike e se rimango in boxer te ne fotti se non sono calvin klein  mi piace quando fai certe cose certe cose quando fai certe cose mi piace quando piace quando fai certe cose certe cose quando fai certe cose mi piace quando piace quando fai certe cose certe cose quando fai certe cose mi piace quando piace quando fai certe cose certe cose quando fai certe cose mi piace quando piace quando fai ',
 '     volo in alto su  ste cime  e tu stai bene dove stai presa bene come il weekend  eh tu non uccidere il mio vibe non uccidere il mio viiibe  viiibe non uccidere il mio viiibe  viiibe  nuovi trick  nuovi flow  nuova bitch allo show giro con la gang  gli altri fanno wow   nuova she  troppo kitsch  nuova hit porto a casa un altro platino  lo chiamo just eat   poi mi dicono chi si accontenta gode sarãxa0 meglio su instagram ma io lo chiamo frode lui vuole fare il duro ma alla fine ã¨ un boy scout bello ciao  lui che dissa me ã¨ tipo un coming out dai non fare la monella vedo la tua bella se guarda male grattatina anti iella   ieri sera a fare bello hai fatto glu glu glu mo  mi chiami  sto occupata tipo tu tu tu   ghiaccio dappertutto come a mosca una rockstar firmo tette  passa l uniposca regola uno  nuovo rito se ã¨ in giro a fare il figo prendi il suo migliore amico  volo in alto su  ste cime  e tu stai bene dove stai presa bene come il weekend  eh tu non uccidere il mio vibe non uccidere il mio viiibe  viiibe non uccidere il mio viiibe  viiibe  ehi  lei mi chiama baby  io la chiamo baby vuole la mia voce come quella bag fendi  yo lei mi chiama sexy  io la chiamo sexy crazy come lei  pensa piã¹ ai cents che ai sentimenti come vola sul tappeto come cinderella troppo a spasso  ti scarto come una caramella dal mezzo su cui compaio pensi sia una super cena e invece andiamo al mc  ti offro la mela tu quando me la ti ã¨ bastato poco  giãxa0 sei fell in love ti ã¨ passato il sonno  baby io non ci sarã²   non mi troverai online  sto uccidendo un altra base non uccidere il mio vibe  volo in alto su  ste cime  e tu stai bene dove stai presa bene come il weekend  eh tu non uccidere il mio vibe non uccidere il mio viiibe  viiibe non uccidere il mio viiibe  viiibe  ti leggo nel pensiero please don t give my vibe sã¬ mi sa che ã¨ vero sai ieri c era una festa sai che c ero ne fumo tanto che dopo ti vedo in bianco e nero bionda sai che hai il culo che ã¨ una bomba mi ti porto nella tomba dell amore neanche l ombra piove sempre sembra londra    un bicchiere ogni tre passi ho tanta roba e me la tengo stretta in tasca fra il nome dell etichetta  volo in alto su  ste cime  e tu stai bene dove stai presa bene come il weekend  eh tu non uccidere il mio vibe non uccidere il mio viiibe  viiibe non uccidere il mio viiibe  viiibe  o yeh yeh yeh ai yeh yeh yeh woo baby k vegas jones gemitaiz woo  ',
 '    baby k  andrã©s dvicio  dã©jame bailar contigo  yo  baby k   baby k  faccio un tuffo sotto il sole fa giãxa0 un caldo che si muore questa estate non si dorme me la bevo come un cocktail questo ritmo che mi muove i problemi sono altrove le cuffie sulla testa viaggio sotto l ombrellone prendiamoci le stelle che il resto non ci serve uscire e fare le sette   andrã©s dvicio  ho voglia di andare piã¹ forte non ci basterãxa0 questa notte voglio vedere le luci dell alba cambiare colore voglio ballare con te  soltanto con te non chiedo la luna ma un ballo con te lasciamoci tutto alle spalle io e te fino a che nasce il sole   baby k  spengo tutto per due ore che mi scordo anche il mio nome bevo birra col limone senza ghiaccio per favore andiamo non so dove diplomiamoci in hangover scottiamoci la pelle poi cambiamoci colore prendiamoci le stelle che il resto non ci serve almeno fino a settembre   andrã©s dvicio  ho voglia di andare piã¹ forte non ci basterãxa0 questa notte voglio vedere le luci dell alba cambiare colore voglio ballare con te  soltanto con te non chiedo la luna ma un ballo con te lasciamoci tutto alle spalle io e te fino a che nasce il sole   baby k  le giornate cosã¬ lunghe notti sempre troppo corte che ti svegli sulla spiaggia col rumore delle onde e mentre la notte finisce dimmi che male c ã¨ se mentre ballo con lui io penso ancora a te   andrã©s dvicio  ho voglia di andare piã¹ forte non ci basterãxa0 questa notte voglio vedere le luci dell alba cambiare colore voglio ballare con te  soltanto con te non chiedo la luna ma un ballo con te lasciamoci tutto alle spalle io e te fino a che nasce il sole   baby k  andrã©s dvicio  voglio ballare con te  soltanto con te dã©jame quiero bailar contigo esta noche bailamos tã¹ y yo   yo  baby k ']
```

is there a way to decode that characters? (like è, à, ç)

here what I tried:

```
for s in l_text:
    print(s.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1'))  

for s in zz:
    print(s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'))  

for s in zz:
    print(s.encode('latin-1').decode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

and all combination of these encodings, but is not working. everytime it changes symbols (for example `ù` "-> from `ã¹` becomes `\xe3\xb9` )

with `s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')` python gives me the well-known error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 402: invalid continuation byte
```

Am I in the correct way? there is some specific encoding that i'm forgetting? or is there another way?

My last option is to drop every word that contains those "uncoded" chars, but I prefer to avoid.

### IMPORTANT

I have no possibilites to change the text at the origin, that's what I am so pleas don't ask me where the text come from.. I have just a txt file with a lot of text like this. The problems are just in italian and spanish..I think.

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def string_cleaner(rouge_text):
    return ("".join(rouge_text.strip()).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8"))
```

Use `ignore` to ignore errors

**Usage**

```
for s in l_text:
 print(string_cleaner(s))
```